# How to compare same table in different environment PROD,DEV

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like know how to compare between the same table in different database environment like Production and development.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1@PROD
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE1@DEV
```

Any hints.

Comment: What is wrong with the SQL you show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create database link on one of environments. Let's say you will create a database link on DEV to PROD and give it grant to select only just to avoid any damaging data.

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK PROD
CONNECT TO <user_name>
IDENTIFIED BY <password>
USING '<service_name>';
```

then to get all differences you need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1@PROD
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

and oposite query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE1@PROD
```

Answer (score 2):

If the two tables have the same columns the best way to compare them, without expensive MINUS operations or joins (and only reading each table once) is like this:

```
select max(flag), col1, col2, ...
from (
       select 'prod' as flag, col1, col2, ... from table1_prod
       union all
       select 'dev'  as flag, col1, col2, ... from table1_dev
     )
group by col1, col2, ...
having count(*) = 1
```

In the GROUP BY, if the row is identical in the two tables it will have the count 2, so it will not be selected. Count 1 will be the case if the row is only in prod or only in dev. A "changed" row will be in both, but with different value in at least one column, so it will really be two distinct groups. "Changed" row only makes sense if the tables have a unique key by which you can match them; you can then identify "changed" rows by comparing the value in the unique key.

Comment: What @ is for connect to different database.